# Sharing an Options Menu between Activity and MapActivity

Tags: android

Sharing an Options Menu between Activity and MapActivity.
Is this possible?

I have an Options Menu shared between multiple Activities but now I need that menu in a MapActivity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define the menu in XML. Put the smarts to load that XML in a static method, then call that method from `onCreateOptionsMenu()` in your various classes. Put the smarts for `onOptionsItemSelected()` in another static method, and call that method from `onOptionsItemSelected()` in your various classes.

Comment: Many thanks. I did try that but the onOptionsItemSelected() contains references to non-statics.  I did try to functionalise further with static methods but to no avail.

Did I give up to early?

Comment: @sugarynugs: I successfully implemented this on a consulting project. It worked fine. Just pass the `Activity` to the static method.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624174/tabhost-what-if-i-need-to-handle-onoptionsitemselected-each-in-separate-tab-acti/5624488#5624488

Comment: @Thunder Rabbit: what are you trying to do?

Comment: @techiServices sorry for late reply.  I can't remember now what I wanted to do.  Three weeks ago was early in My Life With Android.  Now I've been using it for an entire *month* (haha) and am trying to sort out AsyncTask.  ;-P