# TabHost: What if I need to handle onOptionsItemSelected each in separate Tab/Activity

Tags: android

I need to have a `TabHost` consisting of two `tabs` where each `tab` represented by a separate `Activity`. Each `Activity` has its own data fields and methods to operate on them. I want each `tab` to have its own `menu` and for this `menu` I need `onOptionsItemSelected()` method to be a part of the `class` to make it able to invoke methods of this `class`.

What the best approach would it be to implement this?

I've started with `menu` definition in the class which represents `TabHost`, but then faced with a problem I don't have an access to methods of my `Activities`. I decided to make methods of `Activities` `static` to have access to them but finally I would need to define almost all fields of these `Activities` as static which doesn't seem to be a good solution for me.

**Update**:

---

It became much easier then I thought. In onOptionsItemSelected() you can get the current `Activity` of your opened `tab`.

```
SecondActivity sa = (SecondActivity)this.getCurrentActivity()
sa.myPublicMethod();
```

Comment: so did you implement your own interface then? or did you use a static method? or neither?  i don't understand why you have accepted James' answer as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on what sort of functionality you are implementing. You could have each activity implement an interface with the instance methods you need and then have the tabhost contain a reference to the current activity of type interface. If you do this, make sure to update the reference each time you switch to another activity.

Comment: This approach will lead to memory leaks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623197/how-to-keep-always-up-to-date-reference-to-activity

Comment: It only results in memory leaks if you try to keep the reference across changes to the Activity stack. You should be updating your reference just before pushing any changes to the stack.

Comment: The best way to do this would be keep the reference in your own `Application` class and use a cast to `MyApplication` on `getApplicationContext()` to give you access to the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onOptionItemSelected()` in each `Activity` and then call a static method, passing in the `Activity` you are calling from.  You could then check the `class` of the `Activity` and then cast `Activity` to `TabOneActivity` or `TabTwoActvity`.  If the methods you need are public (or friendly, if in the same package) you will have access without the need for them to be static.

Edit:

Create a class like so with the static method to be called from each `onOptionItemSelected()`.

```
class GlobalStaticMethods {
    // Pass in the following as a which (avoids having to check class using SimpleClassName)
    public static final int TabActivityOne = 1;
    public static final int TabActivityTwo = 2;

    public static myOnOptionItemSelected(final Activity activity, final int which) {

        switch (which) {
            case TabActivityOne:

                ((TabActivityOne)activity).tabActivityOneMethod();

                break;
            case TabActivityTwo:

                ((TabActivityTwo)activity).tabActivityTwoMethod();

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, did you mean "Use onOptionItemSelected in MAIN activity"?

Comment: I edited my answer.  Hopefully it makes more sense as to what I am getting at.  You will probably want to pass in other variables as required.

You can use this method from any Activity in your application whether it is Main, TabOne, TabTwo... etc for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot, please see an update to my description - the solution is much much simpler :)

Comment: would you use this solution for this other question too?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611427/sharing-an-options-menu-between-activity-and-mapactivity